# How to see motioneye's recorded movies in a browser?

Tags: camera, motion

I am using motionEye version 0.42.1 (motion Version 4.2.2) over the web interface. When I log in I can see the configured file storage path which is set to /var/lib/motioneye/Camera1 on my device.

I can find the files there. I have setup motionEye to record movies (using motion detection).

But I wonder if I can view the videos over the web interface.

And if not, is there another way to view the files in a browser. Maybe a plugin or another software that plays nicely together with motioneye.

I know I can point a browser to the filesystem, but the filesystem is not always available, for example when viewing remotely or through a VPN.

(I tried to find this in the documentation at https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneye/wiki and did some web searches. I went through all the menus I could find on the web interface several times. Maybe I just did not notice something that is obviously there? I even believe I saw it once in the web interface but cannot remember how I got there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was slight change in click behaviour on the most recent update. I use MotionEyeOS but the behaviour should be the same. Click twice on the streamed image and a menu should overlay the top of it allowing access to the functionality you desire, assuming the logged in user has the requisite permission and they are both enabled in the settings.

Comment: thank you so much! in my case a single click on the live image was enough.

Comment: Yeh a second click is only required when I first open the page, subsequently only a single click is needed